Is there a method in Spring Boot to access the data of a received OAuth2-token?
Currently I am building a Spring Cloud Gateway-application, which should act as an API-gateway between an Angular Frontend and some downstream-services.
So far, the frontend logs into the gateway, which is connected to a keycloak, and receives a session-id (not the token!) for further access. So far so good.
Now I would like to access the JWT-token in the backend to pass it to a downstream-service and to extract roles for RBAC.
The only way, I managed to access it is by using:
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedCliend) {

String token = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

return token;
}

With this, I get the data I need, but I would rather like to get it without doing a GET-request.
How can I access the access-token-value in the Spring-application?
Many thanks!

Preamble
You should probably provide the frontend only with the token claims (or even better, the minimal subset the frontend needs), instead of the signed token string.
Sending the full token:

is a useless security risk (if a malicious OAuth2 client manages to read it, it can usurpate user identity to act on the resource server(s) on his behalf)
makes the server lose some control over access removal: a JWT access token can't be invalidated. If you send it over the network, all you can do is waiting for it to expire.

But if JWT access token remains on the server, you can delete it when ending the user session, instantly revoking the frontend access.
Having the backend expose user data
The gateway could provide OpenID claims with every request as a header or a cookie. For that, an option could be to write a WebFilter using the ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository to extract claims from. But this would significantly (and uselessly) increase the load on the network (and on the gateway).
At the end of the day, it is probably a much better option to have the frontend do a single GET request to fetch user data. Also, this user data is a resource and would probably be better served by a resource server behind the gateway. This is what I do in this article. There, the gateway just routes /me to a resource server which has a @RestController as follows:
@RestController
public class MeController {

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public UserInfoDto getMe(Authentication auth) {
        if (auth instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth) {
            final var email = (String) jwtAuth.getTokenAttributes()
                .getOrDefault(StandardClaimNames.EMAIL, "");
            final var roles = auth.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .toList();
            final var exp = Optional.ofNullable(jwtAuth.getTokenAttributes()
                .get(JwtClaimNames.EXP)).map(expClaim -> {
                    if(expClaim instanceof Long lexp) {
                        return lexp;
                    }
                    if(expClaim instanceof Instant iexp) {
                        return iexp.getEpochSecond();
                    }
                    if(expClaim instanceof Date dexp) {
                        return dexp.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
                    }
                    return Long.MAX_VALUE;
                }).orElse(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            return new UserInfoDto(auth.getName(), email, roles, exp);
        }
        return UserInfoDto.ANONYMOUS;
    }

    /**
     * @param username a unique identifier for the resource owner in the token (sub claim by default)
     * @param email OpenID email claim
     * @param roles Spring authorities resolved for the authentication in the security context
     * @param exp seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time when the access token expires
     */
    public static record UserInfoDto(String username, String email, List<String> roles, Long exp) {
        public static final UserInfoDto ANONYMOUS = new UserInfoDto("", "", List.of(), null);
    }
}

